# SBT skipping tests in all subprojects

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

In order to run assembly without tests, it's recommended to run:

```
sbt 'set test in assembly := {}' clean assembly
```

But when we have a multi-project setup, this doesn't work. I have to do things like

```
sbt 'set test in assembly in sub1 := {}' 'set test in assembly in sub2 := {}' clean assembly
```

But what I'm working on is a generic script that creates jenkins jobs. So I have no knowledge of submodules of our future projects.

Is there a way to exclude tests for all the submodules with a single command?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe `aggregate in test := false` works? It has to be applied to the root project that aggregates the modules.